# Dataframe insert sum of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 df

- df_hist: daily data of share values
- df_buy_data: date when share were bought

i want to add the share holdings to df_hist for each data, which calaculate from df_buy_data depending on the date. in my version i have to iterate over the dataframe which works but i guess not so nice...

```html
hist_data={'Date':['2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-04'],'Value':[23,22,21,24]}
df_hist=pd.DataFrame(hist_data)

buy_data={'Date':['2022-01-01','2022-01-04'],'Ticker': ['Index1', 'Index1'], 'NumberOfShares':[15,29]}
df_buy_data = pd.DataFrame(buy_data)

for i, historical_row in df_hist.iterrows():
        
        ticker_count = df_buy_data.loc[(df_buy_data['Date'] <= historical_row['Date'])]\
                                    .groupby('Ticker').sum()['NumberOfShares']

        if(len(ticker_count)>0):
            df_hist.at[i,'Index1_NumberOfShares'] = ticker_count.item()
        else:
            df_hist.at[i, 'Index1_NumberOfShares'] = 0

df_hist
```

how can i impove this?
thanks for the help!

Comment: could you elaborate your question, please?

Comment: my question would be if there are any pandas functions so i dont have to iterate over the dataframe which is also quite slow when haveing a lot of rows.